# onclick launching javascript that opens a popup window - not sure the function call

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have this code from mailchimp to launch a popup box for a signup form.

I have been struggling to launch the script by onclick function.

I am used to seeing the function name and jsut using that, but in this instance I can work out what should be in the `onclick="XXXX"`.

Script is as follows (I have changed the UUID and LID pars just in case):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us9.list-manage.com","uuid":"changedforsecurereasons","lid":"changedforsecurereasons2"}) })</script>
```

And on the button I was trying to use :

```
<a href="" class="button" onclick="xxxxxx">Sign up here</a>
```

What should "xxxxxx" be?

Comment: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://mc.us9.list-manage.com/subscribe/form-settings?u=changedforsecurereasons&id=changedforsecurereasons2&u=changedforsecurereasons&id=changedforsecurereasons2&c=dojo_request_script_callbacks.dojo_request_script0"

Answer (score 3):

You need to:
 1. Change `href="#"` in `a` tag.
 2. Extract JS code to function `showSubscribe`.
 3. Set `onclick` handler to call function `showSubscribe`.
 4. Remove `MCEvilPopupClosed` cookie.
 5. Call the rest of the code.
 6. Replace the UUID and LID with your values.

```
function showSubscribe(){  
    document.cookie = 'MCEvilPopupClosed=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;';  
    require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) {  
        L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us9.list-manage.com",  
            "uuid":"CHANGE ME",  
            "lid":"CHANGE ME"});   
    });  
}  

<a href="#" class="button" onclick="showSubscribe();return false;">Sign up here</a>
```